# how to get an uid from application's own pamameter?

Tags: android, security

I would like to know an uid from application's own pamameter.
I know how to get an uid from PackageManager with package name, however I have noticed that an application can send a fake package name or context which is created with fake package name. How can I create an API to determine exactly an uid from any app's own parameter? Or how to check this app is system app?

Comment: What do you mean by "own pamameter"?  And no, another application cannot spoof the PackageManager response on a system with an intact security model, as that query is between your app and the system.

Comment: I would like to make an method to check application's uid from parameter, but not just string because string could be faked. so own parameter could be Context like getApplicatioContext(). is it not possible?

Comment: Any user parameter can be faked.  You either need to use a communication channel for which the operating system supports discovering the identify of the sender, or use a cryptographic signing or challenge/response mechanism.  But these both have their own weaknesses - an Android device will happily install an impersonator of a 3rd party app that is not currently installed, and a cryptographic key can (with enough determination) be extracted from an app to create an imposter.  The only truly secure solution is for the user or an external device to validate the authenticity of a given *install*.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to get the current app id. This should do the trick. Get the result of [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myUid()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myUid%28%29) and give it to [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackagesForUid(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackagesForUid%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks but I already knew this way.. I would like to make an method to check application's uid from parameter which cannot be faked and is unique. for example I cannot gurantee with string of package name because an app can pass another package name to the method. do u have another idea?